# Problems attaching cold hose for washing machine

Tags: plumbing, washing-machine, plumbing-fixture, hose

Currently I only have the hot water hose going into our washing machine because the cold hose doesn't seem to want to screw on to the tap. Attached are photos showing the cold hose that doesn't attach, its tap and finally a photo of the hot and cold taps together (see hot tap and hose attached fine). You can see the two taps aren't the same.. I'm wondering if I need some adapter??

The washing machine isn't happy because it can't draw any cold water. The wife isn't happy because clothes are getting worn out quickly. The mother in law is getting involved so things are getting serious.. think I might have to finally fix this. Thanks in advance!

[image: Pipe]
[image: Tap]
[image: Both taps]

Comment: replace that hose, I can see it all the way from Arizona that tread is damaged inside the  hose nut.

Comment: One way to test @knowitall's idea of damaged threads is to try to switch the hoses. Take hot off the hot faucet and screw it onto the cold faucet. Try to put cold on the hot faucet. Don't force them, just gentle finger-turning. If the hot hose goes on cold faucet too, and the cold hose wont go on the hot faucet, then knowitall's diagnosis is correct. If hot hose won't go on cold faucet but cold hose goes on hot faucet, then it's the faucet that is damaged or incompatible threads.

Comment: A trick to getting these to start threading is to turn it BACKWARDS while having it in position... This gives you a "click" that occurs exactly when the threads line up.  Then you turn it forward.   You also have to be very careful about alignment or you end up with a cross-thread (which you seem to have as one thread is slightly damaged).   I wouldn't toss the hose because of that --- The sealing surface is NOT the threads -- I'd just try to repair the thread with a small scratch awl or some such.  Toss it if you can't fix it as you don't wanna cut up the threads on your valve.

Comment: Kyle B + I fully agree I am amazed by all the time I see Teflon tape on hose fittings and this is a waste and dose nothing as the seal is on the end  at the washer or O ring not the threads and tighten a plastic thread should always be done backwards until the click.

Answer (score 1):

I would replace that hose.

It looks like the tread is damaged.

[image: tread]